# Android: Why are there still firebase files in my build and how do I remove them?

Tags: android, firebase, build, build.gradle

I had an Android project which I connected to `Firebase`, so it generated many firebase-related files in the app/build folder when I built it. Now I removed `firebase` from the app, including disconnecting the app using the Firebase console, and removing these lines

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
```

from my app-level build.gradle file. However, when I clean and rebuild, there are still firebase-related folders and files in my app/build directory. Is there an easy way to get rid of them (I don't want to accidentally delete a wrong file)?

Here is and example of the folders:[image]

## Edit:

The solution was to remove the line

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

at the bottom of the `build.gradle` file and remove the `google-services.json` file from app folder.

Answer (score 2):

You can delete build and obj folder. It is 100% safe. Delete both folder and then run your project.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know this. I tried this but when I built again it created the firebase files again. The problem was that there was an extra line in the build.gradle that I forgot to remove.

Comment: @user30189 You may want to send an answer(if it resolved your issue) to your question and accept it instead of editing the question.